template deduction with co_yield
I am trying do to a basic signal/slot library with coroutines. The idea is that you have signal members, connect them with slots that have the same signature, and when you co_yield a signal it calls the registered slots.
Signal class looks like this:
template<typename... T>
class Signal {
public:
    using slot_member = std::function<Slot(T...)>;
    struct SignalArgs {
        SignalArgs(std::span<slot_member> slots, T... args): args(args...), slots(slots)  {}
        std::tuple<T...> args;
        std::span<slot_member> slots;
    };

    SignalArgs operator()(T... args) {
        return SignalArgs(slots, args...);
    }
private:
    (...)
};

The important part is SignalArgs, since when you do a co_yield my_sig(...) it's what the promise sees. the yield values is defined as such:
template<typename... T>
std::suspend_never yield_value(typename Signal<T...>::SignalArgs args)
{
    for (auto f: args.slots) {
        Slot s = std::apply(f(args.args));
        s();
    }
    return {};
}

My problem is with the template deduction:

error: no matching member function for call to 'yield_value'
co_yield s(3, "lil");
^~~~~~~~
note: candidate function [with T = <>] not viable: no known conversion from 'Signal<int, const char *>::SignalArgs' to 'typename Signal<>::SignalArgs' for 1st argument
std::suspend_never yield_value(typename Signal<T...>::SignalArgs args)

Clearly the template deduction doesn't work in this case and I wonder what can I do.

The problem is that Signal<T...>:: is a non-deduced context for T.... What you can do is move SignalArgs out to be it's own template.
namespace detail {
template<typename... T>
struct SignalArgs {
    using slot_member = std::function<Slot(T...)>;

    SignalArgs(std::span<slot_member> slots, T... args): args(args...), slots(slots)  {}
    std::tuple<T...> args;
    std::span<slot_member> slots;
};
}

template<typename... T>
class Signal {
public:
    using slot_member = std::function<Slot(T...)>;

    detail::SignalArgs<T...> operator()(T... args) {
        return { slots, args... };
    }
private:
    (...)
};

template<typename... T>
std::suspend_never yield_value(typename detail::SignalArgs<T...> args)
{
    for (auto& f: args.slots) {
        Slot s = std::apply(f, args.args);
        s();
    }
    return {};
}

